# How to make a transform of return type DataFrame => DataFrame which will give product of 2 column as value and column1_column2 as name

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
Input
+-------+-------+----+-------
| id    |    a  |  b |    c                   
+-------+-------+----+-------
|  1    |  1    |  0 |    1     
+-------+-------+----+-------

output
+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+-------+----+-------
| id    |    a  |  b |    c  |  a_b  | a_c  | b_c            
+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+-------+----+-------
|  1    |  1    |  0 |    1  |  0    |  1   | 0
+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+-------+----+-------
```

basically I have a sequence of pair which contains Seq((a,b),(a,c),(b,c))
and thier values will be col(a)*col(b) , col(a)*col(c) col(b)*col(c) for new column
Like I know how to add them in dataFrame but not able to make a transform of return type DataFrame => DataFrame

Comment: do you want function which take DataFrame as input & return DataFrame as output ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you what?
Take a look at the [API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/sql/index.html) page. You will save yourself sometime :)

```
val df = Seq((1, 1, 0, 1))
  .toDF("id", "a", "b", "c")
  .withColumn("a_b", $"a" * $"b")
  .withColumn("a_c", $"a" * $"c")
  .withColumn("b_c", $"b" * $"c")

output ============
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| id|  a|  b|  c|a_b|a_c|b_c|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  0|  1|  0|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: I dont want hardcoding I want a function which returns a DataFrame => DataFrame :)

Comment: Not sure if I understand. You want the above wrapped in a function and the function takes a DF as an input?